# Heroku, cron, delayed_job and workers (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

I have two questions:

1. How can I add a heroku worker just before running a delayed job and remove it after it finishes?
2. Is my cron.rake ok?

cron.rake:

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku cron add-on"
task :cron => :environment do

  puts "requesting homepage to refresh cache"
  uri = URI.parse('http://something.com')
  Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  puts "end requesting homepage"

  puts "start sending daily mail"
  User.notified_today.each do |user|
    Delayed::Job.enqueue UserMailer.daily_mail(user).deliver
  end
  puts "end sending daily mail"

end
```

I use [collectiveidea delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You maybe can use an "autoscale" plugin like [workless](https://github.com/lostboy/workless) or [heroku-autoscale](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-autoscale).
2. About the cron I don't see any problem on it...

Answer (score 4):

I've had good success with [HireFire](https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire).

Easy setup:

- Add `gem 'hirefire'` to your Gemfile
- Create `Rails.root/config/initializers/hirefire.rb` with the config information.

Answer (score 2):

To add remove/remove workers, hook into your ORM's after :create / after :destroy

With DataMapper on Heroku, I did it like this (You must set the ENV vars yourself)

```
MAX_CONCURRENT_WORKERS = 5
if ENV["HEROKU_APP"]  
  Delayed::Job.after :create do
    workers_needed = [Delayed::Job.count, MAX_CONCURRENT_WORKERS].min
    client = Heroku::Client.new(ENV['HEROKU_USERNAME'], ENV['HEROKU_PASSWORD'])
    client.set_workers(ENV['HEROKU_APP'], workers_needed)        
    puts "- Initialized Heroku workers for ZipDecoder"           
  end

  Delayed::Job.after :destroy do
    workers_needed = [Delayed::Job.count, MAX_CONCURRENT_WORKERS].min
    client = Heroku::Client.new(ENV['HEROKU_USERNAME'], ENV['HEROKU_PASSWORD'])
    client.set_workers(ENV['HEROKU_APP'], workers_needed)        
    puts "- Cleaned Up a Delayed Job for ZipDecoder ---------------------------------"
  end
end
```

Comment: Just be careful doing this since you could kill off a worker that currently has a job in your after destroy block.  Currently there is no way to only kill off jobless workers.

Comment: You could move the destroy code to after happen after a job is complete.. and then shut down that worker. Not sure how to accomplish this..